# jquery POST response successful BUT data empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, response

im using jquery to send a post to a session endpoint of my api to get a login token. the request returns success, however the data is empty. if i do the same request in cURL it returns json.
Im new to jquery. does anyone have any suggestions as to what the problem might be?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML> 
     <HEAD>
      <TITLE>  login </TITLE>      
    </HEAD>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css" />
  <BODY>
    <DIV id="container">
      <DIV id="header">
        <IMG src="image.bmp" alt="logo" style="width:64px;height:64px;"/>
        <H1> my service </H1>
      </DIV>
      <DIV id="content"> 
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
         $("button").click(function()
         {
           $.post("www.mydomain.com/api/session",
          {
            username: "batman",
            password: "123"
          },
        function(data,status)
        {
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>   
             <DIV id="loginform">
               <form  method="POST">
                  Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
                  Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
                  <button> welcome! </button>
               </form>
             </DIV>
          <DIV id="description">
            <P>mydomain description</P>
            <P>Join now to see what people are doing near you!</P>
          </DIV> 
          <DIV id="register">
            <P>Dont have an account with us? </P>
            <P>Register here now !!</P>
          </DIV> 
       </DIV>   
          <DIV id="nav">
        </DIV>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: And you checked the console for same-origin errors ?

Answer (score 2):

WOW! i found the problem, it was so simple. i just needed to use http:// in front of my url. 
Thanks for every ones time and help!.

Comment: Out of interest, did you find you still had to specify a file name in the URL or did it work with the session directory?

Comment: It worked witht the session url (fake, but processed in my routing script). This makes sense as this is the address i cURL at and i get the correct response. Its just that because my mod_rewrite on apache server sends all requests that arent file-locations in the filesystem to the router, regardless of its valididy. And it was treating www,mydomain.api/session as a file address, which doesnt exist, so it just went to the router and did nothing, then exited. I hope you follow what i mean. Thanks for your help

Comment: With http:// it treats it as an address, which correctly redirects to the physical file in the router script

Answer (score 0):

Moreover Punit's answer, I advice to use [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method which is better than `.click()` function.

```
$(function() {
// equals to $(document).ready(function(){ but faster to wright
  $("#loginform").on('click', 'button', function() {
      //Punit's Code (that is good !!)
      $.ajax({ url: 'your_url_here',
           data: {username: 'batman' , password : "123"},
           type: 'post',
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(output) {
                        alert(output);
                    }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: don't really know where it fails ... watch this https://jsfiddle.net/Ganov/y7fwej75/ 
work's since jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 0):

The issue's likely to be that you need to stop the form from being submitted after your button click event is executed. As written, once the script has completed, the page is refreshed and there is no opportunity to process the results of the post request. Return 'false' from the click function:

```
   $("button").click(function() {
       $.post("www.mydomain.com/api/session",
      {
        username: "batman",
        password: "123"
      },
      function(data,status)
      {
          alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      });
      return false;
    }    
   );
```

This done you should see whether your post request is returning any data. Note that because you're posting to a directory, the script will default to looking for an index file, e.g. index.php. If that's an issue, change your URL to point directly to the relevant server-side script.

Comment: i route all requests in my server through one script. with cURL the session url works fine and returns json with an auth token. but now, even with your code (which at least made the code run again), the data is empty. i cant understand it

Comment: im still getting no data. and the response header is empty too. why does it work in curl and not here

Comment: The above works for me with a simple local test setup: I post to a 'session' directory containing index.php which echoes some test data. The resulting data is alerted as expected. Could it be related to the way you're routing requests? If you haven't already, maybe try changing the URL temporarily to point directly to your server-side script and see if there's any difference.

Comment: annoyingly, i do finally get a response, but, its not the correct one that i get from cURLing the clean url, because some variables needed to make the request work are created in the routing script (amongst other things), and this routing script is bypassed if i call the direct file path on the server

Comment: so i essence. it must be called through the routing script as a clean url

Comment: Well that makes sense. At least you know the source of the issue now.

Comment: yes, true. do you have any idea why it would make a difference. because going through the routing file (ie via www.mydomain/api/session rather than pointing at the actual server file) works absolubtely fine in curl as follows..........

Comment: curl -L -X POST -d "username=batman" -d "password=123" "www.thetenticle.com/api/session"  RESPONSE                                                               
{"_links":{"self":"\/api\/session?user_id=25","user":{"href":"\/api\/users\/25"}},"_embedded":{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJTSEEyNTYifQ==.eyJpc3MiOiJ3d3cudGhldGVudGljbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNDU0MjYwOTgzLCJuYmYiOjE0NTQyNjEwNDMsImV4cCI6MTQ1NDQzMzg0MywidWlkIjoyNX0=.1d2f584979e7bc8f10752f9cb2cfc733959da2924f98dd9d84f3cbfbe8162414"}}

Answer (score -1):

Below is the for creating an Ajax call, now what you have to do it. You have to return the data into json format from the URL, then try console.log(output) in the success function, you will get the idea that hot it is works.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'your_url_here',
             data: {username: 'batman' , password : "123"},
             type: 'post',
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(output) {
                          alert(output);
                      }
    });
```

let me know if you dont understand anywhere,

Comment: Thanks ill give that a go. Good info

Comment: Please let us know if your code is online, it will help me a lot to find the proper solution,

Comment: i clearly dont know what im doing. i now have the altered script part: <script> $(document).ready(function() { $("button").click(function() { $.ajax({ url: 'www.mydomain.com/api/session', data: {username: 'batman' , password : "123"}, type: 'post', dataType: "json", success: function(output) { alert(output); console.log(output); } }); }); }); </script>

Comment: ok, i got it,.  What you are doing is you are posting the variable on the url "www.thetenticle.com/api/session".  here our ajax call is working correctly. but the URL we are calling it should return something to us,. currently i dont think if it is returning anything that is why we are getting blank response.   Let me share some linjk with you which may help you that how ajax call is work for checking the username and password.

Comment: ok, but the response is returned with curl. i get a json HAL. ifd youre trying to login via that url it wont work. it needs to be curl 'ed

Comment: firebug will help you . . check the ajax call you have made from the network / xhr if you know it,.  it will show you what you have posted and what you have get in the response.